# the error setter/field for Receiver found on class chat.getReceiver() is shows null

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am creating a chat app but the message are  shown in the fire base but it is not displayed in my screen here is my code gets error in the if condition it is not working because chatReceiver shows null but it should not be?here is my messageActivity code:

```
    private  void readMessage(final String myid, final String userid, final String imageurl){
            mchats= new ArrayList<>();
            ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
            ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    mchats.clear();
                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        Chats chat=snapshot.getValue(Chats.class);
                        System.out.println("test3");
                        if( (chat.getReceiver()!=null&&chat.getSender()!=null &&chat.getReceiver().equals(myid)&&chat.getSender().equals(userid))||
                                ( chat.getSender()!=null&&chat.getReceiver()!=null && chat.getReceiver().equals(userid)&&chat.getSender().equals(myid))){
    
                            mchats.add(chat);
    
                        }
    
                        messageadapter=new messageAdapter(MessageActivity.this,mchats,"default");
                        rv1.setAdapter(messageadapter);
                    } 
    }
```

Comment: Post your adapter code as well.

Comment: And have you added a layout manager to the recyclerview as well?

Comment: Yes bro when i posted the full code many people said post your specific error code

Comment: Print an element of mchats in or after the far loop, see if it actually contains anything.

Comment: Yes bro it doesn't contain anything

Comment: Then the problem isn't with the adapter or the recycler view. The data you are getting is itself null. Find out why, is there actually a reference in your firebase db named as "Chats"? If yes, then check the variables in the "Chats" class, are the all the same as the key values stored in the firebase db?

Answer (score 0):

Add `layoutManager` in your xml inside `RecyclerView`:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:padding="@dimen/margin_small"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_your_item_layout" />
```

You add programetically

```
rv1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```